# How do I toggle overtype mode on a Mac in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

On a PC, I would use the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. How do I achieve this on a Mac, which doesn't have that key?

Answer (score 2):

Mac actually does have an <kbd>insert</kbd> equivalent if you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> (function) and <kbd>Enter</kbd>\<kbd>return</kbd> together, this is the equivalent of insert on a mac and *should* enable overtype mode.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. El Capitan and Google Docs on Safari

Comment: The answer above (use fn + return) does not work - running MacOS 10.14.2 and Google Docs in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

On an old mechanical Apple keyboard, the "help" button above "del" did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

actually i just tried F1 and help and that seemed to do it on the mac